# Why is Flyout detail not populating on android in MAUI, works on Windows

Tags: .net-maui

I have a MAUI app, with the code below. For tablet and desktop. On Windows, it works as expected, when you click an item in the flyout menu the detail content gets populated. However, on Android, nothing happens. I can step through the code and see that it is getting executed. But nothing is displayed. I've trawled the documentation and there isn't anything I can find to explain this behaviour. Can anyone help?

I'm converting an app from Xamarin and its like pulling teeth :(

Here are some video clips of the problem. In Xamarin it was a **MasterDetailPage** so slightly different tech.

[Android](https://photos.app.goo.gl/DdcMZUNvx3LLeNqn9)
[Windows](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Sg2Krg1Df8pqroV17)

Main Page

```
<ScrollView>
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged"
                    Background="White">

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="5,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding IconSource}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                               Margin="10,0"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontSize="20"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="checkw.png" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="16"></Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    
</ScrollView>
```

Code Behind

```
private void collectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as FlyoutPageItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        FlyoutPage page = (FlyoutPage)this.Parent;

        page.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Pages.Claim.Actions());// new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
        page.Title = item.Title;
        //page.IsPresented = false;
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

    List<FlyoutPageItem> pages = new()
    {
        new FlyoutPageItem {Title = "Actions", TargetType = typeof(Pages.Claim.Actions), IconSource = "actionact.png" },
        new FlyoutPageItem {Title = "Agreement", TargetType = typeof(Pages.Claim.Agreement), IconSource = "actionagr.png" },
        new FlyoutPageItem {Title = "Asbestos", TargetType = typeof(Pages.Claim.Asbestos), IconSource = "actionasb.png" },
        new FlyoutPageItem {Title = "Buildings", TargetType = typeof(Pages.Claim.Buildings), IconSource = "actionbld.png" },


    };

    collectionView.ItemsSource = pages;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the Shell Flyout does not initially display all the Shell Content items in its list on Android? May I confirm if you close the flyout and again to reopen it and will you see the correct display?

Comment: No this is not Shell. The flyout part works just fine. I can see the list ok and click items. It's just the detail section isn't populated on Android whereas it is on Windows. I'll see if I can add some video clips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can replicate your problem on my side. Since it's a potential issue and can be tracked on this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10274

Thanks for your patience and feedback!

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me. I'll carry on my development using the Windows target for now. That probably explains why the only working FlyoutPage examples I can find use Shell

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will provide an update if it's been fixed.